# GMod - What can the bots do, and can I 'teach' them?

Tags: garrys-mod

Recently I found a strange console command in GMod:
`bot`
After reading the help menu for it, I tried it out, and it indeed did create a bot. The bot mostly runs around, doing nothing.
I found some other console commands of interest:

```
bot_attack
bot_crouch
bot_mimic
bot_zombie
```

So I was wondering: What can the GMod bots do, can I teach them to do other things, and why are they included if they just sit around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bots in Garry's mod are mostly useless.

You can type `bot_mimic 1` to have it copy your movements.
You can look at what the other cvars do [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=170589737).

I believe when they were added they weren't a priority, hence them sitting around since there aren't any waypoints for them on the maps, and not having many cvars or functionality.

Comment: Is there a way to add waypoints to maps, so I can have them run around?

Comment: You do know that they can be scripted too right?

Comment: NPCs can be scripted using Lua.

Comment: @aytimothy I do. I was just wondering what the pre-made ones can do, since they have a lot of commands. `bot_zombie` is the most confusing one, the help just says "braaaaaiiiins."